# Why is a cuckolded husband "fit for heaven" in Byron's Don Juan?

Tags: meaning, lord-byron, don-juan

[Canto 5, stanza 154](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)/Canto_the_Fifth#CLIV), from Byron's [*Don Juan*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Don_Juan_(Byron)):

> His majesty saluted his fourth spouse
>        With all the ceremonies of his rank,
>   Who clear'd her sparkling eyes and smooth'd her brows,
>        As suits a matron who has play'd a prank;
>   These must seem doubly mindful of their vows,
>        To save the credit of their breaking bank:
>   To no men are such cordial greetings given
>   As those whose wives have made them **fit for heaven**.

What is the meaning of **made them fit for heaven**?

Why would a cuckolded husband be "fit for heaven"?

(According to the plot, "his majesty" is a sultan who has been cuckolded by one of his wives: she ordered Don Juan bought on the slave market and brought to her in female disguise)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how it originated, but the idea that cuckolds go to heaven is apparently an old English proverb/saying, not one that was invented by Byron. *[A Dictionary of Sexual Language and Imagery in Shakespearean and Stuart Literature](https://books.google.com/books?id=2XtWDhgljvkC&pg=PA342),* by Gordon Williams, gives a number of similar examples in the entry for "Cuckolds are Christians":

> Tilley has 'In rain and sunshine cuckolds go to heaven' (R12; the thought occurs from 1591, but this form is cited from 1659). The simplified "*Cuckolds go to Heaven*' occurs in Spinke, *Quackery Unmask'd* (1711) 8; and Leanerd, *Rambling Justice* (1678) Epil. declares: 'both Fools and Cuckolds go to Heaven'.

(p. 342)